# Get Document from payload of file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have payload of `Message<File>`. how to get of type `org.w3c.dom.Document` from Message ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<int:transformer input-channel="foo" output-channel="bar" 
    expression="T(javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory).newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(payload)" />
```